# How to test that objects get updated using a fake repository

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, repository, persistence

Say I have the following business logic:

```
    foreach (var item in repository.GetAll())
    {
        if (SomeConditition)
        {
            item.Status = Status.Completed;
            repository.Update(item);
        }
    }
```

Now I write the following unit test:

```
    public void Test()
    {
        var repository = new FakeRepository();
        repository.Add(new Item());

        RunBusinessLogic(repository);

        Assert.AreEqual(Status.Completed, repository[0].Status);
    }
```

FakeRepository is implemented over a List, and GetAll() simply returns the list.

While I can test most of the logic involved using this approach, I cannot verify that I have remembered to call repository.Update() in the business code. Because FakeRepository.GetAll() returns the actual objects, the repository objects will already have been modified by business code before I call Update(). In fact, FakeRepository.Update() does nothing.

I realize I can use FakeRepository.Update to record that it has been called, and Assert that in the test. But if I forget to call Update, I cannot be trusted to remember to Assert the Update either, right? I would prefer the test to simply fail if the Update call was omitted.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

A mocking framework might be useful here as it allows you to verify which methods are actually called. To name a few:

- [Rhino Mocks](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx)
- [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.com/)
- [moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/)

And here's a [nice comparison](http://www.richard-banks.org/2010/07/mocking-comparison-part-1-basics.html) between those three popular frameworks.

Comment: As I noted above, I can also use my fake repository to verify whether or not Update has been called. But I would like my test to fail even if I don't do that when I have forgotten to call Update in the business code. If my fake repository was more realistic and returned copies rather than the real repository object references from GetAll, the test would properly fail. Thus, using an in-memory database as repository would be one way to solve my problem. But I'd like to know if there are simpler solutions.

Answer (score 1):

> I realize I can use
>   FakeRepository.Update to record that
>   it has been called, an Assert that in
>   the test. But if I forget to call
>   Update, I cannot be trusted to
>   remember to Assert the Update either,
>   right? I would prefer the test to
>   simply fail if the Update call was
>   omitted.

When you notice that you're not testing that Update is called, or you notice that Update isn't called, that's when you write a test that Update is called.  Not that the item in the repository is completed, but that Update is called (it's a different test).  You've decided that it's important to you that Update be called, so you need to test that.  The way to go about it is exactly as you outline - record the call to update in your FakeRepository, and test against that.

Comment: Yes, I am thinking that this must be the way it has to be. But the problem with this is that I will have to wait until the update-missing-bug surfaces until I know I have to test it and fix it. If my fake repository was a little more realistic, and didn't return  real repository object references from GetAll, my test would fail if Update was forgotten.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that can be unit-tested separately here: the `Repository.getAll()` and the `Repository.update()` methods, and the evaluation of the completion condition for each item, or each kind of item. I'm not sure I will use a FakeRepository here.

As suggested, another option would be to have the `FakeRepository.update()` method recording and/or counting the number of updates.

> But if I forget to call Update, I cannot be trusted to remember to Assert the Update either, right?

Correct, but when you follows the TDD process, you will fail your test first - red - then you write the code to make it pass - green. You will write the assertion first, causing the test to fail, and then invoke the update() method, making the test pass.

Comment: Yes, we can test GetAll and Update with integration tests, and the completion condition with unit tests. But these could all be green even if we forget to call Update in my example loop. In other words, I am never told that I need to call Update.

Comment: GetAll() and Update() can be unit-tested as well, I'll rephrase my answer. A common metaphor for TDD is dual entry bookkeeping, as such, it *reduces* the probability of making an error, you have to make two errors so that it's not detected.

Answer (score 0):

Given that no answer has been accepted yet, and that the answers are correct (In my humble opinion!), I might suggest that Tor Hovland may be asking a subtly different question:

Specifically, Tor may be asking how to ensure that his *unit tests* call the Update call, and that the unit test should fail in those situations.

If this is the case, there are two things that need to be said:

Firstly, if this is important, consider adding test code to the TearDown() or appropriate method in the unit tests, however this has the problem in that it isn't actually testing that the application code is correct - there might be application code that fails to call the Update call.

If there is application code that doesn't call the Update() correctly, and the code just happens to rely on that (Who knows why...  Perhaps the code has a bug that just happens to work because it doesn't call Update?), and a developer modifies the libraries such that some behaviour is changed so that Update() is either automatically called, or the buggy code in question now calls it, you now have a change in functionality that your unit tests do not test because they *always* call Update.

So, this leads to the second point that needs to be said - the unit tests need to test what the application code does. It doesn't really matter if the unit tests are "Not using the code in the strictly correct sense of the design", what matters is that the unit tests test the results of the code itself. In other words, test that the *code* calls Update(), or alternatively, test that Update()'s side effects are present.

To re-iterate, and rephase my somewhat long-winded answer, **don't test the tests**.

Comment: You are probably correct in that I am asking a subtly different question, but that question is: how do I implement a fake repository that is as realistic as a database in that no state actually changes until Update has been called?

Answer (score 0):

The better way is using Dev Magic Fake, so you can Mock the database and can be permanent too, you can also Mock the UI

Just add a reference to DevMagicFake.dll

And you can code the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(VendorForm vendorForm)
{
   var repoistory = new FakeRepository<VendorForm>();
   repoistory.Save(vendorForm);
   return View("Page", repoistory.GetAll());
}
```

This will save the VendorForm permanent in the memory, and you can retrieve it anytime You can also generate data for this object or any other object in your model, for more information about Dev Magic Fake see the following Link on CodePlex:

http://devmagicfake.codeplex.com

Thanks

M.Radwan